# How to make Oauth authentification with msal in a react native app

Tags: react-native, oauth, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I had the opportunity to made Microsoft Azure authentication (msal) on several react applications without any problems.

So I already have the clientId, tenantId for auth configuration.

I now want to perform authentication on a react-native application

I tried to use 'react-native-msal' package but it was archived.

I have since seen the 'react-native-app-auth' package and tried to introduce authentication like this example https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/azure-ad-2irtz?file=%2Fpackage. json%3A10%2C28

but I get several errors

- unable to find Sign in
- problem with session/local storage cache

I tried to use @azure/msal-browser instead of msal but failed to perform authentication

in 2024, what package do you use for Oauth authentication? Do you have any documentation to recommend to me?

Thank you.